# Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters

Tags: support, bug, edits, limits

I fixed the formatting to an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026981/are-the-terms-external-ip-address-and-public-ip-address-synonomous/14027023#14027023) but was unable to proceed as I hadn't changed 6 characters. I added a couple links to utilities mentioned.

I then noticed the links weren't displaying correctly as they were inside ` ` and I was able to remove them successfully.

How come I was able to change only 2 characters this time?

Comment: Most likely the diff didn't see your edit as being just two characters, but as something more substantial. Deletion of the full "code section" and replacement of it with a link for example.

Comment: According to the revision, you added the links from scratch, they were not present before your edit.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes but the second revision I made removing the `` is what I'm wondering about. I don't know why the [revisions history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14027023/revisions) only shows I edited it once.

Comment: If you make more than one edit within 5 minutes period, they are all merged into one edit. This applies both to full scale edits and suggested edits as far as I know.